# How do I turn off auto-accent in a foreign keyboard (brazilian portuguese)?

Tags: windows-11, keyboard-layout, typing

**I want to turn off auto-accent** (a.k.a.: automatic diacritics) from my brazilian Portuguese keyboard. Is that possible?

I have only found posts saying that to do that I need to enable the "US" keyboard layout, instead of the "international US", but that is not my case, and if I do that, then the keys won't match the characters I'm typing, because my actual physical layout is the "Portuguese (Brazil ABNT2)". I have searched a lot and found no answer, it is starting to drive me a little crazy .

#### Explaining more in detail:

- I write mostly in english, and use the "~" symbol for marking and tagging somethings on my notes.

  - With auto-accent, when a press the "~" key, for example, nothing appears on screen until I press another so it gets a accent on it (e.g.: ~ + a = ã). So: **I need to press "~" AND then SPACE for it to appear**, which is *SUPER ANNOYING!*
  - **All I want** is that, **when I press the "~" key, then the "~" character appears immediately**. <strike>Why is that so hard to figure out?</strike>
- When I actually want to use accented characters, I prefer using the "Quick Accent" function from "Window's Power Toys", so I don't even need the auto-accent!

If someone can figure this out for me, I will be extremely grateful